# Clean up .gradle forlde on MacOS

Tags: macos, gradle, storage

I'm trying to clean up some space on my Mac, and I have noticed that `.gradle` folder takes `4.49GB`.
Inside it, I can see that there is a `cache` folder that is `1.23GB` large and `wrapper` that is `3.18GB` large.
Inside the `wrapper` folder I can see such a structure:

```
gradle-2.13-all     
gradle-3.1-bin      
gradle-3.5-rc-2-bin 
gradle-3.5.1-bin    
gradle-4.2-all      
gradle-4.2.1-bin
```

And so on. So this looks like some old data that is still present.
I did not found any gradle command to clean up it's old data nor dit I found whether this data is important.
So the question is what can be deleted in order to free some space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can safely delete the whole `.gradle` folder if you don't need to work offline. This folder will be recreated as soon, as you will run any Gradle task. And Gradle will download some of the the previously cached dependencies and wrapped Gradle versions automatically.

For sure, you likely have cached more dependencies and wrapped versions, you need at the moment, so it can make some free space for you.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle `4.10` and later will clean up that folder for you and remove unused files automatically. See the [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/release-notes.html#periodic-cache-cleanup).